# How can i create element from values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, attributes, createelement

I want from an array to create element and specific an  selected attribute with the values of the array.
Lets say something like for each value to create an option to select element.

I tried to fetch the values in order to create option attribute but i made only one option without a value.

Comment: Show the real code you've done, not an imaginary one!